# Why does the KeyPress event Not fire in primeng?

Tags: jquery, typescript, primeng, onkeypress

Why does the code below not fire in primeng, but works perfectly in jquery?

**PrimeNG Snippet (Does not work!)**

app.component.html

```
<div class="p-field p-float-label">
    <input pInputText id="weight" name="weight" maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="data.weight" (onkeypress)="isValidWeight($event)" />
    <label for="float-input">Weight (Kg) 0.5 - 500</label>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
isValidWeight(event): void {
    const key = event.keyCode;
    if ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || key === 46) {
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

**HTML & jQuery Example (As mentioned works flawlessly)**

app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Playground</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="element" name="element" />
    
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $( "#element" ).keypress(function(e) {
                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    if ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || key == 46) {
                        return;
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

StackBlitz - Unavailable as StackBlitz was throwing annoying issues when trying to create a vanilla html/jquery example.

Comment: To make the PrimeNG code work as expected, ensure that your event handler (onkeypress)="isValidWeight($event)" is correctly defined in your Angular component and that you're using Angular's FormsModule for ngModel.

Comment: it's `(keypress)` not `(onkeypress)`, edit it please, it should works.

Comment: @Mouayad_Al Thanks, I thought I had tried that option as well, as I tried `keypress`, `(onkeypress)`, `onkeypress`, `KeyPress`, `OnKeyPress` etc. without any success.